# "What is the opposite word for X?" Is the sentence correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, prepositional-phrases

I always use:

> What is the opposite **of** X ?

But today I came across:

> What is the opposite word **for** X ?

Are the both grammatical?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, both are grammatical, but the second should be punctuated

> What is the opposite word to "X."

You need to understand the distinction between the use and the mention of a word.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use–mention_distinction

Comment: You are incorrect. "The opposite of" is correct.

Comment: @user45266 is it the only correct option?

Comment: Not sure, but "opposite to" doesn't work. "Is in opposition to" works, and so does "antonym of".

Comment: @AndrewTobilko User 45266 does not have a clue what he is talking about. See here for ngram, which shows "opposite to" and "opposite of" both have a long history in English: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=opposite+to%2Copposite+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Copposite%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Copposite%20of%3B%2Cc0